# Java - Start a thread when the current thread is completed

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to launch a new thread when the currently running thread exits?
The code i have written for a framework starts a thread and it locks(not a java concurrent lock) a file.
I need to process the same file,but i am not able to do so as the lock is held by the thread 
launched by the framework. My requirement is to launch a new thread which processes the file
once the thread launched by the framework is completed

Thanks,
Senthil.

Comment: [See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

Comment: The answer to the title is:"It is possible, but why not loop instead?". My answer to the description is: "Is the `synchronized` keyword what you want? "

Comment: No i donot have control over the currently running thread. It is locking some files which i would also like to process. Not sure how synchronized would solve the problem. Can you brief it more?

Comment: @akaIDIOT join method suspends the currently running thread till the new thread is completed, this is not what i want. I want to launch a new thread when the currently running thread exits.

Answer (score 1):

Use Thread.join() method
Refer [Example](http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html)

Refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Comment: join method suspends the currently running thread till the new thread is completed, this is not what i want. I want to launch a new thread when the currently running thread exits

Comment: @user330482 Why can't you launch two threads and have the second join on the first?

Comment: First thread is launched by the framework i dont have any control over that. :(

Comment: You don't have access to the other thread?  Do you have control of the runnable?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic code structure should be like his

```
public void run(){
//prepare
synchronized{
//Access File
}
//non-trivial statements
}
```

Comment: The lock i meant is not on any of the java objects. It locks one of the file in the filesystem. The file is not accessible till the running thread is completed. So only way i am thinking of right now is chaining a new thread which starts when the currently running thread exits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that launches a second thread at the end of another thread:

```
public class TwoThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class SecondThread implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Start of second thread");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

                System.out.println("End of second thread");
            }
        }

        class FirstThread implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Start of first thread");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

                // Second thread gets launched here
                new Thread(new SecondThread()).start();

                System.out.println("End of first thread");
            }
        }

        new Thread(new FirstThread()).start();
    }
}
```